# Feasibility Check: Image scanning and PDF generating App with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron, twain

I need to replicate a desktop application which currently builds an catalog for coins, medals and banknotes. Its main features are:

- Scan image from a scanner
- Serve the image to an image editing program for some minor adjustments (brightness/contrast)
- The possibility to scan 2 images and stitch them together to one. (e.g. 2 sides of a coin. Side A left, Side B right)
- generate a "printable" PDF file (Printable means: 300dpi and CMYK Profiles)

I know my way around the web stack (JavaScript, HTML5, CSS, PHP, MySQL) so currently I am looking into building an Electron App. For the scanning I found these:

- [CLScan](http://www.commandlinescanning.com/)
- [TSSCAN](http://www.terminalworks.com/remote-desktop-scanning)
- [Dynamic Web TWAIN](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx)

Right now I am trying to estimate if this could be done with Electron/NodeJS and one of those command line tools. 
As for the catalog PDF generation, I found some PDF-Generating Libs and npm packages but all of the seem not to fit a printers press requirements. In the worst case I automate my InDesign workflow more and build the catalog inside InDesign, but if possible, I would like to create a "one-click" solution.

The app will be used on Windows 7.

To cut a long story short: Am I "out of my league" with this kind of challenge and my set of skills I have at hand? Or is this possible?

Comment: I *think* your one-click solution is too broad ... Anyway, since your target seems to be a professionally laid out document, you are probably best off making the final PDF with InDesign. This has the advantage that you can slowly build up the pre-processing process, automating one step at a time, while still being able to produce *something*.

Comment: Okay, what about the image acquisition? Since the catalogs usually contain up to 2000 items I need a ordered and managed way to get the images. Is the proposed way feasible?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/Asprise/scannerjs.javascript-scanner-web-twain-wia-browsers-scanner.js

Comment: Might be a long shot but does anyone have an update on this?

Comment: @S.Ramjit No, I abandoned the project because the real life requirements changed.